# Вывод данных однократно в цикле while(1)

Tags: c

Столкнулся с такой нелепой проблемой и не могу понять, как ее решить.

Пишу программку под МК (но это имеет мало значения, проблема чисто программная) на чистом СИ. Главное условие, что есть процедура инициализации `void main (void)`, и в ней обязательно должен быть цикл `while(1)`, то есть бесконечный без условия.

Есть функция считывания данных, по которым должна идти отправка (вывод) - `read_adc` и `putsf("oo")`.

Логика такая:

```
while(1) {
if (read_adc() > 700) {
putsf("oo");
} else {
putsf("");
}
}
```

Так вот сейчас, когда `read_adc() > 700`, он выводит `putsf("oo")` до тех пор, пока она больше 700, ну, в принципе так и должно быть.

Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы `putsf("oo")` вывелось однократно, а затем, когда оно снова станет меньше 700 и потом больше, снова один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема действительно какая-то нелепая.

```
bool printed = false;
while(1) {
  if (read_adc() > 700) {
    if (!printed) {
      putsf("oo");
      printed = true;
    }
  } else {
    putsf("");
    printed = false;
  }
}
```

Либо

```
while(1) {
  while (read_adc() <= 700)
    putsf("");
  putsf("oo");
}
```

Comment: Только, наверное, лучше сделать 2 флага -- `printed_more` и `printed_less` и печать только "переходы".

Comment: @avp В вопросе говорится про однократный вывод только "oo", а про то, что нужно пустоту по-другому выводить, ничего не сказано :)

Comment: Это верно. 

Возможно, автор просто до такого (а также не надо дублировать вывод пустоты) еще не дошел.